# Convertir registro a número laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola amigos tengo un problema, no se realmente como realizar una suma en laravel. 
Primeramente recojo el registro perfectamente pero a la hora de realizar la suma me dice que tengo que **convertir el registro a número**, he intentado castearlo de diversas formas pero sin resultado. Este es el error que me salta:**Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int**

Código

```
 public function agregarHoras(request $request)
{
    //Pasamos el rquest del post agregar horas

        $operarioHoras = new operario();

        $operarioHoras = $request->nombre;

    //Seleccionamos el registro 

    $hora2 = operario::select('precioHora')->where('nombre', $operarioHoras )->get();

    $hora3 = (int)$hora2;

   return $hora3;

}
```

PD: creo que el problema esta que si le hago un return a $hora2 lo que me devuelve es:

```
[{"precioHora":12}]
```

Necesito o bien quitarle los corches comillas etc al return o castear el registro correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te esta diciendo que no puedes convertir un `Collection` en `Int`, eso es porque la consulta te devuelve un Collection primero desde recorrer el `collection` y convertir el valor, puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```php
$hora3 = (int) $hora2->precioHora;
```

Podrias probar de la siguiente forma tambien:

```php
$horas = operario::select('precioHora')->where('nombre', $operarioHoras )->get();
foreach ($horas as $hora) {
    $hora3 = (int) $hora->precioHora;
}
```

Comment: deberia crear algun tipo de instancia para el fragmento que me has pasado? Es que me da error de que no existe la la instancia en la collecion,

Comment: Podrías mostrar el error que te da para ayudarte mejor, edite la respuesta para que pruebes de otra forma recorriendo el resultado de la consulta con un `foreach`

Comment: la segunda parte brutal amigo muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si traes mas de un registro en la consulta se te va a sobreescribir el valor de `$hora3`